Scaling or normalizing a matrix to get a symmetric, PD and non-expansive matrix
I have a symmetric matrix $A$, I want to scale or normalize this matrix in a way that the resulting matrix is:

Symmetric
Positive Definite
Non-expansive (i.e. all eigenvalues should be smaller than 1.)

So I want to find matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $B=P_1AP_2$ have above mentioned properties.
I know some matrix scaling algorithms like Sinkhorn-Knopp that result a doubly-stochastic matrix which has eigenvalues that their absolute values are smaller than 1 (i.e. $ -1\leq \lambda \leq 1$).
But I'm looking for an algoirthm that results a Positive Definite matrix which means all eigenvalues should be greater than 1 and also I want the resulting matrix be symmetric and non-expansive.
I did a search and found Sinkhorn-Knopp but it doesn't provide all three properties that I want.

can you specify what exact operations are allowed for "scale or normalize this matrix"? how about $\rho A^{\top}A$ for small enough $\rho$?

I think eigenvalue decomposition of A will be good enough to figure out $P_1$ and $P_2$
